# Do ISO grammars follow a specific format

Tags: c#, c++, grammar, iso

Here is a extract from the grammar section of the C# Language Specification:

[image]

1. Is this written in a specific format? I looked at the grammar section in an old C++ ISO I found and it seemed to follow the same format, so is there some standard being used here for writing this grammar? I ask because I would like to be able to create a tool where I can paste the grammar directly and have a working C# parser immediately.
2. Microsoft seem to release their C# spec for free, but I can't find the C++11 format anywhere. Am I going to have to buy this to view it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a variant of BNF that used by Yacc. Yacc normally has `;` as part of its syntax, but changing that makes things simpler with a language like C# and C++ in which `;` is very significant in itself. Unlike most BNF variants, it has a `:` where often BNF uses `=` (see also Van Wijngaarden grammar and you'll soon know much more than the little bit of knowledge that this answer is coming from).

ISO don't have a rule on which grammar must be used in their standards, so others use BNF, ABNF, EBNF, Wirth syntax and perhaps others.

ISO standards often originate as national or other standards that are then adopted by ISO. Since different standards bodies use different grammars (The IETF use ABNF in RFCs [itself defined in RFC 5234], BSI and the W3C use different variants of EBNF, and so on) the grammar in an ISO often reflects its origins.

This is the case here. Kernigan and Ritchie used this format in their book, *The C Programming Language*. While the ANSI standard and later ISO standards differed in the grammar itself, they used the same format, and it's been used since for other C-like languages.

Answer (score 1):

Each standard does its own thing. But among compiler writers there's a fairly standard way of describing grammars, and that's what you're seeing here and in the C++ standard.

Comment: There is an ISO standard for Extended BNF (ISO/IEC 14977). From your answer, I get you hadn't had to follow it.

Comment: @AProgrammer - right. I wasn't aware of 14977, but language standards aren't required to follow it. There is a set of requirements for standards, but they're intended to be more generally applicable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of the [backus naur form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) of grammars that you are seeing here. While not exactly the standard format it is pretty similar. This is generally the standard way of showing how the language is supposed to be parsed, and a common input to parser generators.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard is not available for free. You can buy a copy for 30 USD at webstore.ansi.org. Search for document number 14882, and then look for the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to describe a grammar is using either [Backus-Naur Form (BNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) or [Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form). If you are looking to parse a language easily in C#, take a look at [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) which is a language toolkit for C# and it allows you to use something very similar to EBNF to describe the grammar.

On top of those grammars, there is also [Parsing Expression Grammar (PEG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) but I don't believe it is as common as BNF or EBNF.